# Can we make the tags more visible when reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: feature-request, tags, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, the "tags" are at the bottom, and if the post is lengthy, one can sometimes miss taking a look at them to see if they were edited. Also, the suggester might forget to mention in the edit summary that he edited the tags.

**Feature request**: Can we move the "tags" to be more visible when reviewing suggested edits? Maybe right above the question title?

**Example**: Here's a question I reviewed a few days ago:

[image]

I thought "fine, he just added the images. All is good". However, the images made the post lengthier. I then scrolled down, and found this:

[image]

**Suggestion**: I know it contradicts the layout of the site, where the tags are always at the bottom, but what could be done is: if the tags were edited, they would be moved to the top, like this:

[image]

And if they weren't edited, they'd stay at the bottom.

Comment: I don't have access to the review queue (heck, I think that was my suggestion, sorry about not commenting), but I see your request fair enough.

Comment: The [tag:lid] tag should die! But I like your idea.